# Javascript- send the clicked object as parameter in onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In function clickCircle, i want to use the li which is being clicked. So i want to receive it as a parameter.

```
<li class="circle" onClick='clickCircle(this)'></li>
```

But what should i send as an actual paramenter? ie in place of 'this'.

Comment: `function clickCircle(chooseSomeNameThatMakesYouHappy) {...}`

Comment: your code should work as you requested, what is not working exactly?

Comment: `this` is what you want to send.

Comment: Since you can use jquery, you should bind the click handler in js so it is unobtrusive. The clicked element in jquery would be $(this)

Comment: I downvoted because this is the most basic of client-side language tutorials. Chapter 1, lesson 1!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `this`:

```
function clickCircle(obj) // the li element clicked in the current scope
{
    var element = obj;  // This is the DOM object being clicked
    var $this = $(obj); // This is the jQuery object being clicked

    // Use DOM object like
    element.style.color="#ff0000";

    // Use jQuery object like 
    $this.css('color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: I had to Google this because I made the mistake of using "this" in the function declaration, so that errored out but that was just a brain fart for me...

Comment: You are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<li class="circle"></li>
```

```
$('.circle').on('click', function(event) {
  event.target // your element
});
```

Comment: The question isn't about jQuery

Comment: You could've submitted another answer to don't carry over the downvotes.. And as you edited it while it was deleted, I'm not able to remove my downvote as it counts as not edited (seems like a bug). Or maybe it was because you edited it inside the 5 mins grace period.

Comment: Why not? `jquery` is in the OP's tags.

Comment: @edi9999 it's labeled jQuery, so one can assume the author uses jQuery

Comment: Even with the jQuery, that's not what you'd do.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, what's bad about editing the answer if it wasn't right?

Comment: @intuitivepixel: It's not that you edited it. It's that you changed it to a completely different answer.

Comment: @intuitivepixel It is no problem, I just meant that downvoters most often don't stick around to remove their DVs after you've deleted, fixed and undeleted an answer.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, is this disallowed?

Comment: No, but the votes were given for something entirely different. You'd have been better off posting a new answer.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, you are right, my bad :/ next time I'll leave it and create a different one

Comment: About CrazyTrain's first comment, not entirely sure of the meaning but I'd assume it is because `event.target === this` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the first parameter as the element.

## HTML

```
<li class="circle" onClick='clickCircle(this)'></li>
```

## JS

```
clickCircle=function(element)
{
console.log(element)
console.log(element.tagName) // This will show LI
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/WhVLm/

Comment: Probably even? No.  (this) refers to the element as an object, (event) refers to the event itself. `this.value` or `this.indexOf()` would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('li.circle').on('click', function () {
    clickCircle($(this));
  });
});

var clickCircle = function (param) {
  // your code here
  // param.css('color', 'red').html();
};
```

or with raw javascript:

**HTML**

```
<li id="circle" class="circle"></li>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');

circle.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  clickCircle(e.target);
});

var clickCircle = function (param) {
  // your code here
  // alert(param.nodeName.toLowerCase());
}
```